# Dirichlet Problem in Stochastic PDE Section of Probability Textbook.

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-analysis

I recently started learning about stochastic calculus and stochastic PDEs, and I don't know where to begin with some of the problems in my textbook.  Any help with the following or a push in the right direction would be appreciated.  This is in the section on stochastic PDEs, but it's not clear what techniques from the section are useful here.

Let D be the open unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $u^{\epsilon}\in C^2(D)\cap C(\overline{D})$ be the solution to the Dirichlet problem:

$\epsilon \Delta u^\epsilon + \frac{\partial u^\epsilon}{\partial x_1}=0$, 
$u(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in\partial D$ where $f$ is a continuous function on $\partial D$.

Find the limit $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}u^{\epsilon}(x_1,x_2)$ for $(x_1,x_2)\in D$.

Comment: Can you write down the stochastic process whose generator is the left hand side of the PDE?

Comment: I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Alright, well a place to start is to consider that stochastic process, namely the one satisfying $dX_t=e_1 dt + \epsilon dW_t,X(0)=x$, where $e_1$ is the first coordinate vector. It turns out that the solution to the Dirichlet problem is $E[f(X_\tau)]$ where $\tau$ is the first time to hit the boundary starting from $x$. So now your trajectory is "almost" directly to the right for small $\epsilon$, so one would expect that the limit is close to $f(y(x))$ where $y(x)$ is the point on the circle directly to the right of $x$. Is it exactly that, or is it something else?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on the *hitting distribution* of the boundary. (Indeed, the probability to hit a subset of the circle $A$ is given by the solution to the Dirichlet problem where $f=1_A$.)

Comment: The process associated $(X^1_t,X^2_t)$ is given by $dX^1_t=dt+\sqrt{2\varepsilon}dW^1_t$ and $dX^2_t=\sqrt{2\varepsilon}dW^2_t$. In other words, $(X^1_t,X^2_t)=(t+\sqrt{2\varepsilon}W^1_t, \sqrt{2\varepsilon}W^2_t)$. Finding the hitting distribution is the problem.